# How can I compare the contents of two text files in python

Tags: python, compare

Hello i need to write a script like a wrote in title so i want to give an example for what i want :

file1.txt's content:
New York
Los Angeles
Miami

file2.txt's content:
New York
Orlando
Miami
Dc

i just want to compare two diffrent txts and print the diffrent added or missed elements

if you dont understand what i mean my ex-code is here :

```
from difflib import Differ

from numpy import diff

myfile1 = input("Enter First File's name for compare : ")
myfile2 = input("Enter Second File's name for compare : ")

ch1 = myfile1.split(".")
ch2 = myfile2.split(".")

if ch1[1] == "txt" and ch2[1] == "txt":
    with open(myfile1) as file_1, open(myfile2) as file_2:
        differ = Differ()

        for line in differ.compare(file_1.readlines(), file_2.readlines()):
            print(line)
    
else:
    print("File format Eror !")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can ı give my github project's link for explain ?

Comment: Look at the Standard Library module `difflib`. It does what you want (though perhaps not quite in the way that you want it) and more besides.

Comment: i already use that but if some content is missed this thing is adding "-" in front of name also if content is added "+" adding front of name i need to print added and missed contents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the single characters you can iterate over them:

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as file: # Same thing with file2
    content1 = file.read()
...
```

Like this:

```
min_len = min(map(len, (content1, content2)))
for i in range(min_len): # use smaller length
    if (content1[i] != content2[i]):
        # You found a difference between this two characthers
        # Do something
    # content1 has some extra from content1[min_len:], so you do something with it
```

---

If you want to compare the characters in the words you will have to `split` the input before:

```
content1 = file.read().split(' ')
```

Comment: would it not make sense to iterate over the `min()` of the two and then just consider the longer one from then on? avoids error handling

Comment: i dont mean like. look my project and you will understand what i mean but in my project i cannot select values of start with "+" and "-"https://github.com/ayazarm/Instagram-Follower-List-Bot/blob/main/Instagram%20Follower%20List%20Bot/compare.py

Comment: Would you suggest an edit to my answer? It sounds to me like a good idea, but I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: yes im suggesting an edit .Also i mean im just want to compline two diffrent txt file's contents and write added and missed content's. Please run my code in mygithub you will understand

Comment: https://github.com/ayazarm/Instagram-Follower-List-Bot/blob/main/Instagram%20Follower%20List%20Bot/compare.py

Comment: Ok @Cresht, now I understand, I was about upvoting your edit but it was my own answer 

Answer (score 0):

first read all lines of files

```py
with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    a = f1.readlines()
with open('file2.txt') as f2:
    b = f2.readlines()
```

for reading files in python 3.10 or higher

```py
with (
    open('file1.txt') as f1,
    open('file2.txt') as f2,
):
    a = f1.readlines()
    b = f2.readlines()
```

and now for print differences between file `a` and `b`

```py
import difflib
a_sample = a[0] # 'New York Los Angeles Miami'
b_sample = b[0] # 'New York Orlando Miami Dc'
diff = difflib.ndiff(a.replace(' ', '\n').splitlines(keepends=True), b.replace(' ', '\n').splitlines(keepends=True))
print(''.join(diff), end="")
  New
  York
+ Orlando
- Los
- Angeles
- Miami+ Miami
?      +
+ Dc
```

and iterate all the files:

```py
for file1_line, file2_line in zip(a, b):
    diff = difflib.ndiff(
                  a.replace(' ', '\n').splitlines(keepends=True), 
                  b.replace(' ', '\n').splitlines(keepends=True)
           )
    print(''.join(diff), end="")
```

What's the meaning difflib symbols:

| code | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| '- ' | line unique to sequence 1 |
| '+ ' | line unique to sequence 2 |
| ' ' | line common to both sequences |
| '? ' | line not present in either input sequence |

**Note:** you can iterate in diff output and print only `+` or `-` words.

python document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Comment: hi first of all thx can you help me how can i do this jobs with files (txt) the all other things is correct. im just want to compare my txt files's content (added and missed texts)

Comment: @AyazARMUTLU I edited the answer and write about how to read files